# Mono android extremely slow to warm up

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I have a small app, first screen is a login activity, loading the first activity is relatively ok (2 seconds in emulator).

When you press login button, it use System.Net.HttpWebRequest to validate the login user name/password, it takes about 12 seconds. I call same URL in desktop with 0.1 second. Even worse thing is, the data returned from the URL is json, I need to deserialize it, and it takes extra 10 seconds.

I googled here and their, it rules out the System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Proxy pitfall (7 seconds to detect).

I put some debug, and find out in the Debug window the following interesting result. Basically I notice there are quite a few assemeblies being loaded at runtime.

```
08-14 15:06:12.713 I/dalvikvm( 9180): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
08-14 15:06:17.823 D/dalvikvm( 9180): GC_CONCURRENT freed 50K, 4% free 7313K/7559K, paused 11ms+3ms
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
**Loaded assembly**: System.dll [External]
[0:] 
[0:] 
[0:] 
start login,8/14/2013 3:06:22 PM
08-14 15:06:23.723 I/mono-stdout( 9180): 
start login,8/14/2013 3:06:22 PM
[0:] 
start login,8/14/2013 3:06:22 PM
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
**Loaded assembly**: Mono.Security.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
[0:] 
end login,8/14/2013 3:06:29 PM
08-14 15:06:29.933 I/mono-stdout( 9180): 
end login,8/14/2013 3:06:29 PM
[0:] 
end login,8/14/2013 3:06:29 PM
[0:] 
[0:] 
**Loaded assembly**: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
[0:] 
08-14 15:06:38.893 I/dalvikvm( 9180): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
```

Comment: Should you not be asking this to Xamarin? Try Xamarin Forums or create a bug request on bugzilla.

Comment: There are variety of non Xamarin things that could be causing this. For grins what happens when you deploy to device do you have the same issue?

Comment: @MohibSheth right, I will ask Xamarin. thanks.

Comment: @snowCrabs I experience the same issue with real device, more or less same time.

Comment: maybe you need to enable somehow the --server flag that has just implemented in mono master, but for mobile: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/e86837b7d28558b34d38f54d4d7e99a97f1aae1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out.

I create a new AVD, with better configuration, and it's faster then.

It's slow in emulator also related to the ARM performance is not really good at all. I believe we can use x86 emulator for a better performance. And rather than hard disk, using SSD will help improving the performance.

And with a proper setting of real device and good network, the whole process only takes less than 1 second.